# Javascript Regular Expression to format text to thousands including decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to give format to an input on blur where a number is typed. So if I type: 1234 and blur out of the input, the input take this format: 1.234.
I got this working with this regular expression 
`/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g` and this replace string value `$1.`. Like this:

```
value.replace(this._mask.regex, this._mask.replaceString)
```

...until decimals where included.

So when I type 1234,9999 I get 1.234,9.999. I am kind of a beginner with regular expressions and I want to add something to the existing regular expression that avoids formatting the values after the comma.

Comment: `value.replace(/(\d*)(\d{3})$/, "$1.$2")`

Comment: What for numbers less than `1000`?

Comment: Try using `Number#toLocaleString`. Trying to format numbers with regxp is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
console.log(1234.5678.toLocaleString("en-us", {maximumFractionDigits: 10}));
console.log(1234.5678.toLocaleString("de"));
```

If your input is coming from an input field, then to make sure you are getting `Number#toLocaleString` and not the default `Object#toLocaleString` that a string input would give you, do:

```
Number(input.value).toLocaleString(...)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion to avoid using regexp to format! Thank you. It works!